# How does one make createElement('IMG') clickable?

Tags: click, createelement, setattribute, event-listener

My goal is to make the bottom Queen, a created element, clickable the same as the top Queen. How does one accomplish that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p><button onclick='createAnImg()'>Create Card</button></p>
<img src='Card Deck/QueenHearts.png' onclick='alert("You picked the Queen of Hearts!")'>
<p id='card_holder'></p>

<script>
function createAnImg() {
x = document.createElement('IMG');
x.setAttribute('id', 'Queen_of_Hearts');
x.setAttribute('src', 'Card Deck/QueenHearts.png');
x.setAttribute('width', '72');
x.setAttribute('alt', 'Card Face');
document.getElementById('card_holder').appendChild(x);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's the path to the PicasaWeb Queen of Hearts image if you need it:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-KBSwW1xXPt4/VY12U034XEI/AAAAAAAAASE/5C_uZ_o64QE/s96/23.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
x.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("You picked the Queen of Hearts!")');
```

to your attributes.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p><button onclick='createAnImg()'>Create Card</button></p>
    <img src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-KBSwW1xXPt4/VY12U034XEI/AAAAAAAAASE/5C_uZ_o64QE/s96/23.png' onclick='alert("You picked the Queen of Hearts!")'>
    <p id='card_holder'></p>
    
    <script>
    function createAnImg() {
    x = document.createElement('IMG');
    x.setAttribute('id', 'Queen_of_Hearts');
    x.setAttribute('src', 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-KBSwW1xXPt4/VY12U034XEI/AAAAAAAAASE/5C_uZ_o64QE/s96/23.png');
    x.setAttribute('width', '72');
    x.setAttribute('alt', 'Card Face');
    x.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("You picked the Queen of Hearts!")');
    document.getElementById('card_holder').appendChild(x);
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```